# Encrypt sqlite file for android

Tags: android, sqlite, encryption

We have an android application which use the sqlite database, we will save many images to the file, and then user can download the db file from android client and read the images from our app, and we want to encrypt the file to prevent the attacker get the image directly.

At first, we tried to gzip and encrypted each image before inserted to the db, then we decrypt them during the reading. However we afraid that this may cause performance problem.

Then I found this:

https://guardianproject.info/code/sqlcipher/

And it seems that  sqlcipher use password to encrypt the file, then our app should have to read it by password in the client side, then if someone de-compile our apk, he can still get our password(event this password are retrieved from server) through the source file.

Is this possible? Or do I miss anything?

Comment: Hide your password in a PNG file in the assets or raw folder. This png should and resemble your logo or something like that. Use the Alpha channel to store the ASCII for your password.

Comment: But he/she can still decompile the apk and follow the code the find how I get the password.

Comment: Of course. If they want to reverse engineer your software, there's **nothing** you can do. It depends on how much are they determined to. A perfectly protected software **will never exist**.

Comment: That's right, in fact, I know it, I just want to make the process a little more difficult. :)

Comment: This with steganography isn't so bad. You can complicate it more, by dowloading the image from a server (so it's not directly accessible) and delete it after using it. Or process it without even saving it

Comment: This is a good idea! I will try it. :)